# Python write file in newline

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
    #1 
for line in matched_lines[0:2]:
    #2       
print (line) 
    
    #3        
file = open("pythonsnmp.txt", "w")
    #4        
x = str(matched_lines[0:2])
    #5        
file.write(x)
    #6        
file.write('\n')
    #7        
file.close()
```

In the #2 the result is :

```
(146, '[interfaces.ifTable.ifEntry.ifDescr.8],(STRING),HPE Ethernet 1Gb 2-port 361T Adapter #2')
(162, '[interfaces.ifTable.ifEntry.ifDescr.24],(STRING),HPE Ethernet 1Gb 2-port 361T Adapter')
```

But in the txt file the result is:

```
[(146, '[interfaces.ifTable.ifEntry.ifDescr.8],(STRING),HPE Ethernet 1Gb 2-port 361T Adapter #2'), (162, '[interfaces.ifTable.ifEntry.ifDescr.24],(STRING),HPE Ethernet 1Gb 2-port 361T Adapter')]>
```

If I want the txt file same as #2, how can I code it?

Answer (score 0):

You can unpack the slice as arguments for a call to the `print` function, which has a keyword argument `file` that specifies the file stream to write to:

```
with open("pythonsnmp.txt", "w") as file:
    print(*matched_lines[0:2], file=file, sep='\n')
```